# Pre Tor software for MacOS (not OSX)

Tags: onion-routing, mac

I am looking for information regarding (discontinued) software for MacOS which I believe worked in a very similar way Tor does. I remember using it in late 1990s/early 2000s, but I can't recall its name (JAB possibly?). If I remember correctly it was developed by some German university(ies).

I tried searching the Internet but it seems I don't remember enough information or the software was too niche to be remembered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called JAP/Java Anonymizing Proxy otherwise known as JonDoNym.

In 2003 the network operators were compelled by the German Federal Bureau of Criminal Investigation to log mixes within the network for connections visiting specific websites. They subsequently added code to allow the deanonymization of users upon request.

https://geti2p.net/en/comparison/other-networks

https://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Anon_Proxy#Privacy

Comment: Do you have more info? I don't want to use it, I am just looking for information about it. I am just curious...

Comment: I'll take a look if I have some links...

Comment: https://geti2p.net/en/comparison/other-networks

Comment: http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html

Comment: remember - it was owned by LEO's, illegally. So don't use it